# Scrolling down to class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to frequently (e.g. every minute) update [this news website](https://www.finanznachrichten.de/) and afterwards scroll down to "Zeit" (="time") each time...

[image: eafter]

...which equals `class="Zeit ft-vsbl ft-first-column"` in HTML-code. For the updating-part I found [this handy Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tab-reloader/?src=search), which luckily also allows to run some Javascript/jQuery code snippet after each reload and I used this possibility for the second part of scrolling down by passing this code to the add-on:

```
var $container = $("html,body"); var $scrollTo = $('.Zeit ft-vsbl ft-first-column');

$container.animate({scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top - $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop(), scrollLeft: 0},300);
```

This worked for some time like a charm. Unfortunately, however, something — probably in the structure of the website — recently changed and this code no longer scrolls down to the desired position (it just scrolls down too little) and I lack the Javascript/jQuery knowledge to adapt the code accordingly.

Can somebody please help me and get 10 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must have stopped working because the website structure has changed like you said. With the current version of the website `var $scrollTo = $('.Zeit ft-vsbl ft-first-column')` cannot identify the part to scroll into (it returns nothing).

Let's make it simple. `id` is usually better to identify an element because `id` is meant to be unique. `id` is prefixed with `#` in a query selector.

```js
document
  .querySelector('#WNachrichten_Marktberichte_Home_Index')
  .scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
```

Website structure may change anytime. I recommend learning the technique for yourself. Here're the references.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer because your code works as is, just it doesn't scroll to the desired position but to its container id and I must save that space. Could we adapt that code so that it scrolls to class="Zeit ft-vsbl ft-first-column" (=the *second* class with that name in that website)?

Comment: How about replacing `.querySelector('#WNachrichten_Marktberichte_Home_Index')` with `.querySelector('#WNachrichten_Marktberichte_Home_Index .Zeit.ft-vsbl.ft-first-column')`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, my friend, `document
  .querySelector('#WNachrichten_Marktberichte_Home_Index .Zeit.ft-vsbl.ft-first-column')
  .scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });` did the trick — my thanks and 15 points go to you! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with that Firefox addon, but it works properly in console.
I would recommend just to delete this part
`- $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop()`

Like this:

```
var $container = $("html,body"); var $scrollTo = $('.Zeit');

$container.animate({scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top, scrollLeft: 0},300);
```

This will always scroll to your element $('.Zeit'), even if you are in the bottom of the page. And the old code supposed that you are always at the top of the page. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer because if it worked it would scroll to the desired position, just unfortunately it doesn't scroll at all in my case. Maybe it's because class names are not unique (maybe that's the change in the website) — could we take id=WNachrichten_Marktberichte_Home_Index as var $container (because that id is unique) and within that id scroll to class="Zeit ft-vsbl ft-first-column" ?